# Spring, IllegalStateException when opening page with form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and I get this exception, when entering campaigns.jsp with browser.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'campaign' available as request attribute
```

I have this controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminIndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/secure/campaigns.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String campaigns() {
        return "campaigns";
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/secure/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("campaign")
                            Campaign campaign) {

        return "campaigns";
    }   
}
```

Campaings.jsp (if I remove this part, it shows the page correctly) :

```
<form:form method="post" action="create" commandName="campaign">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="question">Question</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="question" />
        </td>       
    </tr>    

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Campaign"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  

</form:form>
```

I suppose there is a problem with mapping `action="create"`, I am not sure where it is pointing to. I thought it is pointing to the same place as the .jsp is. This is address I use `http://localhost:8080/server/rest/admin/secure/campaigns.jsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<form:form method="post" action="create" commandName="campaign">
```

expects a *model attribute* (or *command object*), an `HttpServletRequest` attribute in reality, with the name `campaign` to use as a template for the form fields.

You haven't added a request attribute with that name. You need to do that before the view is rendered. For example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secure/campaigns.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String campaigns(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("campaign", new Campaign());
    return "campaigns";
}
```

The object doesn't need to have any fields set since it is only used as a template.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I can accept in 9 minutes :). I thought that Spring is checking form, if it has "action" path prepared correctly!

Comment: @libik You're welcome. One other thing you should probably fix is that `action` attribute. Don't make it relative. Precede it with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` (in this case, the full value would be `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/secure/create`), so that it is obvious where it is going. If you ever end up copy pasting the form to another JSP that is rendered in a different path, you don't want to have to ask yourself: "Why is it going somewhere else?".

Comment: thanks. If I understand correctly, in this context and full address : `http://localhost:8080/server/rest/admin/secure/campaigns.jsp`, the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is `http://localhost:8080/server/rest/admin/` ?

Comment: @libik `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` will only give you your web application's context path. But that path will be absolute (relative to the host), ie. start with a `/`, for example `/server`. In a browser, that path will be appended to your current host and port to produce `http://localhost:8080/server/...`.